# accessibility: Camera switches and switch access users: typing with the eyes closed through Morse Codes

Tags: accessibility, camera-switches, switch-access

Currently, users navigating the phone through the switch access accessibility feature navigate the phone, and enter, text, ...

by looking at the keyboard keys and entering then by navigating through them.

I wonder, whether, it is possible to enter text by entering Morse Code codes.

Here is the Wikipedia article on [Morse Codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morse_code?wprov=sfla1).

This, would have the advantage, that if the disabled user with limb impairment that wanted to navigate the keyboard to enter text, wanted to close their eyes (for instance, they may be tired), or they may even be a blind user, then they could raise the eyebrows, smile, or open the mouth, for different lengths of time, to enter the morse codes. The user could configure which of these three gestures to use for their purpose, according to need and preference.

This could be comfortable. The user could be lying in bed, and be wanting to enter something while in a relaxed state.

This, could make for more, comfortable and relaxed typing.

Would this be at all possible, with current Android accessibility support?

Is anyone willing to implement this?

Thank you for your continued help and support.

Let's make this platform better for all and everyone.

Thank you.

(I would like to congratulate and support the camera switch access and switch support team for listening to user needs, and, implementing, useful or essential user accessibility features).

Thanks.

EDIT:

Here is a link to a [Camera Switches tutorial video](https://youtu.be/4fWEfYRlB2A?si=MKJX4qbqEXXQi7Ds).